# Что значит "question.choice_set.all"? Помогите понять код

Tags: html, python, django

Не могу понять этот кусок:

```
<ul>
    {% for choice in question.choice_set.all %}
         <li>{{ choice.choice_text }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Что делает цикл, что за choice_set.all и как они связаны с choice.choice_text?
Вот модели:

```
import datetime
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone


class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')

def __str__(self):
    return self.question_text

def was_published_recently(self):
    return self.pub_date >= timezone.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)


class Choice(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)

def __str__(self):
    return self.choice_text
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это называется [связанные обьекты](https://djbook.ru/rel1.9/topics/db/queries.html#related-objects):

`question.choice_set.all` - означает выбрать все   `Choice` связанные с текущим вопросом - то есть те  `Choice`, которые ссылаются на данный `Question` через поле `ForeignKey(Question,...)`. `All` в конце вернёт итерируемый queryset, который будет содержать набор соответствующих Choice.

Ну а с `choice_text` вообще все просто: т.к каждый элемент полученного `queryset`-а будет являться экземпляром `Choice`, то вы можете из него обращаться к любому полю модели `Choice`